# Exponential function leads to unsolvable logarithm.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Problem:

$f(t) = 0.75 * 10^{kt}$ where k is a constant. We know that  $f(2)=3$. Find $f(3)$.

My approach:

Rewrite $f(2)$ as: $0.75*10^{2k}=3$

Try to solve for k, eliminate 0.75 first: $10^{2k}=4$

This is where I get stuck: $log_{10}4=2k$

Where do I go from there? Am I doing something wrong? The answer is supposed to be $f(3)=6~$

Edit: typo in the logs, fixed. And I solved it, thanks everyone!

Comment: You don't need the value of $k$ explicitly (though you pretty much have it), the value of $10^k$ is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement $10^{2k}=4$ doesn't imply $2k=\log_4(10)$; it implies $2k=\log_{10}(4)$. So, you have that
$$
k=\frac{\log_{10}(4)}{2},
$$
and therefore
$$
f(3)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot 10^{3\log_{10}(4)/2}.
$$
Your task now is to use the laws of logarithms/exponentials to simplify this expression.